# Getting rid of magic numbers in BoundedNumericProperty errorhandler

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to using BoundedNumericProperty.
I need to limit the value of a variable, let's say named "saturation", from 0 to 1, so that if I try to set a value greater than 1, I will get 1, if less than 0, then 0.

I learned that it can be done like this:

```
saturation = BoundedNumericProperty (
                            0.1,
                            min = 0,
                            max = 1.,
                            errorhandler = lambda x: min (max (x, 0), 1))
```

This code works correctly but it is not convenient enough because of errorhandler.

As you can see the problem is that I have unnecessary magic numbers in errorhandler (0 and 1), which duplicate min and max arguments values.

I looked at different examples of using BoundedNumericProperty on Github, and I see this thing in almost all examples.

Instead, I would like to simply write something like:

```
saturation = MyProperty (
                            0.1,
                            min = 0,
                            max = 1.,)
```

and I would like this property to work this way:

```
class MyProperty(BoundedNumericProperty): 
    def __init__(*args, min=0, max=1, **kwargs):
         super().__init__(*args, min=min, max=max, errorhandler=lambda x: min(max(x, min), max), **kwargs)
```

But here I get

```
super().__init__(*args, min=min, max=max, errorhandler=lambda x: min(max(x, min), max), **kwargs)
 RuntimeError: super(): no arguments
```

(python3)

How to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
class MyProperty(BoundedNumericProperty):
    def __init__(self, *largs, **kw):
        my_min = kw.get('min', 0)  # 0 is default
        my_max = kw.get('max', 1)  # 1 is default
        kw['min'] = my_min
        kw['max'] = my_max
        kw['errorhandler'] = lambda x: min(max(x, my_min), my_max)
        super().__init__(*largs, **kw)
```

another example (without using lambda):

```
class MyProperty(BoundedNumericProperty):
    def __init__(self, *largs, **kw):
        self._my_min = kw.get('min', 0)  # 0 is default
        self._my_max = kw.get('max', 1)  # 1 is default
        kw['min'] = self._my_min
        kw['max'] = self._my_max
        kw['errorhandler'] = self._my_errorhandler
        super().__init__(*largs, **kw)

    def _my_errorhandler(self, x):
        return min(max(x, self._my_min), self._my_max)
```